# opportunity how to show the close date show msg close date in near throw on vf page

Tags: apex

shows the message(Close date is near) on opportunity when a particular opportunity's close date is 5 days ahead

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Lightning Experience suggestion from @Raspi, for Salesforce Classic, you can simply create an image formula field that looks like this:

```
IF (TODAY() + 5 = CloseDate,
  IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif" , 'Yellow' ,12,12) & ' Close Date is imminent. Do something!' & BR(),
  NULL)
```

and place the formula field on the page layout, perhaps in an untitled section at the top.  I use this technique to display 'soft alerts' that appear only when viewing a record. You can have many image expressions within one formula field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it in the current Record Page as 'advise' ?

I usually use a **Lightning component** with some rules, using **TOAST** advises. An invisible Lightning component that handler the INIT and if some rules are true, then i call 'showToast' function:

```
showToast : function(component, event, helper) {
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams({
    "title": "Close Date is near!",
    "message": "The Close date is 5 days ahead!",
    "type": "warning",
    "mode": "pester"
});
toastEvent.fire();}
```

See documentation here: [Lightning Component Show Toast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_showToast.htm)

IMPORTANT! : Just for **Lightning Experience Layout**. If do you need for **Salesforce Classic**, you must build a Visualforce Page with an 'alert()'.